Do all modifiers always simultaneously belong to both dependents and adjuncts?
Here I was told that any modifier is simultaneously a dependent and an adjunct:


Here I came across a different opinion:

The term "adjunct" includes "modifiers in clause (or VP) structure together with related supplements" (p. 59); thus it does not include modifiers within an AdjP.


Do all modifiers always simultaneously belong to both dependents and adjuncts?
If not, then why not?

Update:
I'm interested in every your opinion but mostly I'd like to get the answer in terms of the textbook "the Cambridge Grammar of the English Language" (CGEL).
Both answers containing the opposite opinions above say they both are based on CGEL's terminology. And it seems very sad to me because either CGEL is a poor textbook which wasn't able to explain one of the very important things of their syntactic analysis or the structure of this forum is such that it doesn't allow to identify what answers are right and what are wrong.

According to the Cambridge Grammar of the English Language, the term adjunct covers modifiers and supplements in clause structure, not in the structure of phrases such as prepositional phrases, adjective phrases, noun phrases, etc.

"We use the term ‘adjunct’ to cover modifiers in clause (or VP)
structure together with related supplements" (59)
"the term ‘adjunct’ covers modifiers in the VP or clause together with
related supplements" (665)

In phrases, there is no mention of adjuncts:

"Prototypical NPs...are phrases headed by nouns and able to function
as complement in clause structure... One important kind of dependent
found only in the structure of NPs is the determiner...Other
dependents in NP structure are modifiers or complements" (54,55)

The image at the other question is not meant to apply to all types of clauses and phrases. You'll notice as well that there is a 'determiner' in the 'dependents' category, but clauses don't take determiners, only noun phrases do.

Do I understand correctly that CGEL implies: 1) All modifiers in clause structure simultaneously belong to both adjuncts and dependents; 2) All other modifiers belong only to dependents, but not to adjuncts ? Thanks.

@Loviii Yes, that's correct.
